# Is there an easy way to finding lore items?

Tags: diablo-iii

I seem to find myself mousing over every book in every room to see if it has any meaning - reading, xp, etc.  Is there an easier way of finding if an item of importance exists in my current view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quest items appear with a faint gold glowing particle effect.  See the crown at 8:35 in this video.

Answer (score 2):

> It is currently unknown whether or not lore books will be tied into
>   the achievement system, but it's likely that many players will want to
>   collect all available books in the game. Some books are sensitive to
>   quests, where if the player misses them during a quest step, they will
>   have to repeat the quest to attain the book. This list will eventually
>   house the location of every lore book in the game. The following is
>   listed by when the book becomes available to the player
>   chronologically, not when they were recorded. A static spawn is an
>   item spawned in a pre-set area, and will always appear during a
>   specific event or in a specific area. A dynamic spawn does not have a
>   100% chance to spawn, and it will also usually spawn in multiple
>   locations.

**[Source](http://www.diablowiki.net/Lore_Book#Collector.27s_Guide)**

This is still incomplete, but soon they will complete all acts with all books. ATM there is only ACTI with some books.

The easier are:

- Leah's Journal: from Leah's room (depend on which quest you are)
- Lore Book in Deckard Cain's house

Answer (score 0):

Taking in account my experience so far in the game, what i realized is that, lore itens (such as green books) can be found in dead bodies ( those you have to click in order to drop its content) and in places that are not hidden such as pedestals (like in the act 1 dungeons).